# Firebase Configuration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am working on project which use **Firebase**.

I have added all [Pod files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccwr0.png) in my project. I have also added [Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ddk.png) but it shows me [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYYGp.png). I have also link all libraries of **Firebase Podfile**. I followed all instruction provided by [Google Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) but it is not solving my error. Please help me into this.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code/Podfile, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: I am not started coding yet. It is issue of configuration of firebase. I just created project and put this Pod file into it @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved it successfully.
As per in my question Add framework related too firebase

Add this Linker flags too for firebase configuration

[image]